# pipenv - Pipfile.lock is not being generated due to the 'Could not find a version that matches keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev' error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pip, tf.keras, pipenv

As the title clearly describes the issue I've been experiencing, no `Pipfile.lock` is being generated as I get the following error when I execute the recommended command `pipenv lock --clear`:

```
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev
Skipped pre-versions: 2.5.0.dev2021020510, 2.5.0.dev2021020600, 2.5.0.dev2021020700, 2.5.0.dev2021020800, 2.5.0.dev2021020900, 2.5.0.dev2021021000, 2.5.0.dev2021021100, 2.5.0.dev2021021200, 2.5.0.dev2021021300, 2.5.0.dev2021021400, 2.5.0.dev2021021500, 2.5.0.dev2021021600, 2.5.0.dev2021021700, 2.5.0.dev2021021800, 2.5.0.dev2021021900, 2.5.0.dev2021022000, 2.5.0.dev2021022100, 2.5.0.dev2021022200, 2.5.0.dev2021022300, 2.5.0.dev2021022317, 2.5.0.dev2021022400, 2.5.0.dev2021022411, 2.5.0.dev2021022500, 2.5.0.dev2021022600, 2.5.0.dev2021022700, 2.5.0.dev2021022800, 2.5.0.dev2021030100, 2.5.0.dev2021030200, 2.5.0.dev2021030300, 2.5.0.dev2021030400, 2.5.0.dev2021030500, 2.5.0.dev2021030600, 2.5.0.dev2021030700, 2.5.0.dev2021030800, 2.5.0.dev2021030900, 2.5.0.dev2021031000, 2.5.0.dev2021031100, 2.5.0.dev2021031200, 2.5.0.dev2021031300, 2.5.0.dev2021031400, 2.5.0.dev2021031500, 2.5.0.dev2021031600, 2.5.0.dev2021031700, 2.5.0.dev2021031800, 2.5.0.dev2021032213, 2.5.0.dev2021032300, 2.5.0.dev2021032413, 2.5.0.dev2021032500, 2.5.0.dev2021032600, 2.5.0.dev2021032610, 2.5.0.dev2021032700, 2.5.0.dev2021032800, 2.5.0.dev2021032900, 2.6.0.dev2021033000, 2.6.0.dev2021033100, 2.6.0.dev2021040100, 2.6.0.dev2021040200, 2.6.0.dev2021040300, 2.6.0.dev2021040400, 2.6.0.dev2021040500, 2.6.0.dev2021040600, 2.6.0.dev2021040714, 2.6.0.dev2021040800, 2.6.0.dev2021040900, 2.6.0.dev2021041000, 2.6.0.dev2021041100, 2.6.0.dev2021041200, 2.6.0.dev2021041300, 2.6.0.dev2021041400, 2.6.0.dev2021041500, 2.6.0.dev2021041600, 2.6.0.dev2021041700, 2.6.0.dev2021041800, 2.6.0.dev2021041900, 2.6.0.dev2021042000, 2.6.0.dev2021042100, 2.6.0.dev2021042200, 2.6.0.dev2021042300, 2.6.0.dev2021042500, 2.6.0.dev2021042600, 2.6.0.dev2021042700, 2.6.0.dev2021042800, 2.6.0.dev2021042900, 2.6.0.dev2021043000, 2.6.0.dev2021050100, 2.6.0.dev2021050200, 2.6.0.dev2021050300, 2.6.0.dev2021050400, 2.6.0.dev2021050500, 2.6.0.dev2021050600, 2.6.0.dev2021051200, 2.6.0.dev2021051300, 2.6.0.dev2021051400, 2.6.0.dev2021051500, 2.6.0.dev2021051600, 2.6.0.dev2021051700, 2.6.0.dev2021051800, 2.6.0.dev2021051900, 2.6.0.dev2021052000, 2.6.0.dev2021052100, 2.6.0.dev2021052200, 2.6.0.dev2021052300, 2.6.0.dev2021052400, 2.6.0.dev2021052500, 2.6.0.dev2021052600, 2.6.0.dev2021052700
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

So, how can I overcome this situation? I'm basically developing a deep neural network using `Keras`. I simply installed the following dependencies without explicitly declaring versions:

```
tensorflow = "*"
nltk = "*"
pandas = "*"
tweepy = "*"
textblob = "*"
seaborn = "*"
matplotlib = "*"
wordcloud = "*"
stop-words = "*"
vadersentiment = "*"
scikit-learn = "*"
keras = "*"
```

Comment: By looking at the pypi site for [`keras-nightly` library](https://pypi.org/project/keras-nightly/#history), I could see that there are no versions named `2.5.0.dev`. Check which package is generating the error and try downgrading that package.

Comment: what's your tf version? and why choose the nightly package?

Comment: @Kishore no, it does, it will install version `2.5.0.dev2021032900`

Comment: It seems the reason behind this package is tensorflow `2.5.0`, which is the latest stable version. After I've downgrade it to `2.4.1`, `Pipfile.lock` was generated. Thanks for your comment. Could you please post this comment as an answer to let me mark it as answer? @Kishore

Comment: @talha06 Glad to help. Sure, I'll post it in the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the `pypi` site for [`keras-nightly` library](https://pypi.org/project/keras-nightly/#history), I could see that there are no versions named `2.5.0.dev`. Check which package is generating the error and try downgrading that package.

Answer (score 2):

Pipenv wants you to use the `--pre` flag in this situation. I think the simplest way to install it would be like this:

```
pipenv install tensorflow --python=3.8 --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently, `tensorflow` arises a sub-dependency resolution error with `Pipfile` when resolving `keras`. It searches for a version that matches `keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev`. Looking at `pypi`, this version does not exist.

Whatsoever, installing a version 2.4.X works, e. g. `pipenv install tensorflow~=2.4.1`.

Answer (score 0):

By Changing the `python_version` in `pipenv` file resolved my issue.

I had it `3.9` before.

**`Pipfile`:**

```
python_version = "3.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tensorflow does not work on python 3.9 as it has a dependency on the nightly.

If you are using python 3.9, your option is to go to tensorflow 2.6.0rc1,

Answer (score 0):

adding those line to Pipfile fixed my issue.

```
[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```